# Build an iOS framework with react native dependency

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, frameworks

I'm trying to create an "iOS framework" that is dependent on react-native. I've built the app in react native, and I'm trying to link it to other apps via framework/library. The idea is that the user will use the framework and use a present view controller method to attach my part of the app to theirs.

I've seen that a lot of people create static libraries that are always downloaded into node_modules using npm, but all files are public - I would like to have it like a framework where the end-user only sees the public headers.

Do I have to separate the app into two parts - a framework and a react-native library?

What is the correct way of creating this kind of framework that the user will have access to my app without giving out too much code?